# data interpretation

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

let us consider following picture and  question:

[image]

INCOME: 1. Money from fund raising programmes, 2. Grant from the government, 3. Contributions from individuals, 4. Contributions from corporations, 5. Contributions as commodities. EXPENDITURE: 1. Education of the illiterate, 2. Food for the poor, 3.Management and salary of staff, Expenses to organise fund-raising programmes. Above charsts show the amounts of an NGO Income for the year $1998-1999 = 55 Mn.$ Expenditure for the same year = $54Mn$.

question :

If the government stops the grant and the expenditure pattern remains the same, then what will be the decrease in the money spent for the education of illiterate?

now  what i have done is that  if income is $55$,then for grant,proportion from this income to grant is  $55*(50/360)=7.64$,if we will stop  granting, he will  have left $55-7.64=47.36$,for  Education of the illiterate is $54*(150/360)=22.5$,what else i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 7.64 will now not be distributed among projects, so Education for the illiterate will lose $7.64*\frac{150}{360}$